# C++ how to print out array values next to each other rather than underneath

Tags: c++

I have made this section of code and would like it to print out like so:

```
Element Value
  0       0
  1       0
  2       0
  3       0
  4       0
  5       0
  6       0
  7       0
  8       0
  9       0
```

Instead of being underneath of each other. Could any one point me in the correct direction?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int n[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int x[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    std::cout << "Element" <<std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout  <<n[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Value" <<std::endl;
    for(int y = 0; y <10; y++)
    {
        std::cout  << x[y] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "size of array: " << sizeof(n) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: dont use stuff that you dont understand. Or more positively: Do understand the stuff that you use. If you tell your program to print a newline it will do so, if you dont want to print a newline, just dont do it.

Answer (score 0):

Print the values next to each other in one loop instead of using two loops (I changed the contents of `x` to make sure we see what's going on):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x[10] = {5,8,1,2,4,6,7,1,0,9};

    std::cout << "Element  Value" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << "    " << i << "     " << x[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "size of array: " << sizeof(x) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/vAaLyl

Output:

```
Element  Value
    0     5
    1     8
    2     1
    3     2
    4     4
    5     6
    6     7
    7     1
    8     0
    9     9
size of array: 40
```

Other than that, there's no need for the array `n`; use your index as the index.